# AWS Cloudfront CDN: Prevent videos from being downloaded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, html5-video, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS S3 to store my private MP4 files to be rendered on my site. Besides, I also have AWS Cloudfront distribution to speed up the content delivery. S3 bucket has Policy to be accessed from my site and OAI so content can only be accessed using distribution.

Problem I'm facing is my videos are downloadable using browser extension though absolutely path of video is blocked outside of the site. Is there I can do to avoid it?

Any help/direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If the browser needs to play the video then it will need to download it.

As you say, it is not that hard to download/capture the file so you have to consider what your goals are.

The usual approach is to accept that it can be downloaded and encrypt the file so that only users with access to the decryption key can play back the content.

The tricky part then becomes how to securely share the decryption key with authorised users in a way that neither they nor a third party can view or share the key. This is the essence of nearly all common DRM systems.

You can use a proprietary way to share the key securely, even something as simple as via some other communication channel, if this addresses your requirements. It will likely not be leveraging the full security capability of the devices, such as a secure media path, but it may be enough for your needs.

If not, then you will probably want to look at one or more of the common DRM systems in use today - you generally need multiple ones to cover all devices and clients, Widevine for Android, Chrome etc, FairPlay for Safari, iOS and PlayReady for xBox, Edge etc.

Comment: Thank you Mich for detailed explanation